# Mongo-db container shuts down after 30 s

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am developping a web app which has two containers the first container is a web app developed in flask and the second a mongodb image. I want to run them at the same time so I have written the following docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
   flask:
      build: .
      depends_on:
         - mongo
      ports:
         - "5000:5000"
      volumes:
         - ./flask:/flask
   mongo:
      image: mongo:latest
      ports:
         - "27017:27017"
      volumes:
         - ./dump:/dump              # data
         - ./datos_db:/data/db       # persistance database
```

First I run `$docker-compose build` with no errors,then I get the following error when I run `$ docker-compose up`:

```
mongo_1  | 2019-10-30T16:18:47.420+0000 error connecting to host: could not connect to server: server selection error: server selection timeout
mongo_1  | current topology: Type: Single
mongo_1  | Servers:
mongo_1  | Addr: localhost:27017, Type: Unknown, State: Connected, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection(localhost:27017[-121]) connection is closed
mongo_1  | 
practica4_mongo_1 exited with code 1
```

As I understand it the container waits too much time for `localhost:271017` to be open and decides to shut down. (I have also tried with port 49155)

Is there anything I am missing and that makes my docker crash?

Comment: Are your ports blocked in your firewall?

Comment: ufw is `Status: inactive`

Comment: erased every container and image and tried to build again and it works!